# Wordpress WPML multi-domain Google Analytics Cross-Domain Linking

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, google-tag-manager

I've set up plenty of Google Analytics cross-domain setups before but for some reason this isn't working in the current scenario:

Domains:

- `domain.com.au` with `UA-XXXXXX-1`
- `domain.co.uk` with `UA-XXXXXX-2`

The two domains point to the same Wordpress Multi-Site using the WPML plugin setup with separate domains as opposed to sub-domains or sub-folders.

Google Analytics (deployed via the same GTM container on both domains) has the following in the general GA Pageview Tag:

On `domain.com.au`:

- Type: Pageview, Code: `UA-XXXXXX-1`
- cookieDomain: `auto`
- allowLinker: `true`
- autolinkDomains: `domain.co.uk`
- decorateForms: `true`

On `domain.co.uk`:

- Type: Pageview, Code: `UA-XXXXXX-2`
- cookieDomain: `auto`
- allowLinker: `true`
- autolinkDomains: `domain.com.au`
- decorateForms: `true`

Both Analytics Properties have both themselves and the other domain in their referral exclusion lists.

Navigating from one domain to the other has the expected behaviour of appending the `_ga=1....` query string but the source/medium information is lost.

I tested by naviating to one domain via a google search result (and was shown `google/organic` as the source medium) but when I switched to the other domain real-time shows me as `direct/none`. When navigating back to the first domain I again show up as `google/organic` there.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that linked domains are for two domains that use the exact same tracking code.   I don't think linking two domains that use different tracking codes is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more research and experimentation we've found the following. Cross-domain referral exclusion works only when you are using the same UA code to push to. In other words for one UA that tracks `domain.co.uk` and one UA code that tracks `domain.com.au` and then a third UA code that we have come to call `Rollup` which we push traffic from both domains to.

The GA tags in GTM for the Rollup property have the auto-link domains set up for each other and it also has both domains in its own referral exclusion list. This way we can actually see the `google / organic` as the `source/medium` when somebody comes from Google, goes to `domain.co.uk` and then to `domain.com.au`. That visitor will be listed as `google / organic` on URL `domain.com.au/....`.